# ¿Cómo utilizar Reflection para crear un XML?

Tags: java, xml, reflection, reflexión

Cómo podría crear un XML que no sea de una clase en específico? es decir, que solo tome los métodos `set` que serían los valores y que tome los **atributos** de mi clase para las etiquetas.

Esto es lo que estoy empleando para arrojar lo atributos:

```
System.out.println("\nHYP:: ");
        Class pinturaClass = Piezas.class;
        Method[] allMethodsPintura = pinturaClass.getMethods();
        List<Method> settersPintura = new ArrayList<Method>();
        for(Method method : allMethodsPintura) {
            if(method.getName().startsWith("set")) {
                settersPintura.add(method);
                System.out.println(method);
            }
        }
```

Y para obtener el valor:

```
for (Object obj : ListaPiezas) {
            Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
            Field field = org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.findField(clazz, "descripcion");
            org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
            System.out.println("\nValor = "+ field.get(obj));
        }
```

Con base a eso, ocupo crear un XML,
gracias.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Esta es mi clase **Piezas**

```
public class Piezas {

    String posicion;
    String numeroParte;
    String descripcion;
    double monto;
    String cambioPrecio;
//getters and setters

}
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo podría desarrollar un XML en java usando Reflection?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/219080/c%c3%b3mo-podr%c3%ada-desarrollar-un-xml-en-java-usando-reflection)

Comment: Es uno de los apis más lentos que existen, así que no te lo recomiendo para nada. La reflección la sabes hacer, tal vez lo único que necesites preguntar es como serializar a xml.

Comment: @RuslanLópez excto!, es lo que llevo semanas...

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, trata de poner un [mcve], ya que por ejemplo, no sabemos si tu clase Piezas usa genéricos

Comment: @RuslanLópez gracias, la acabo de añadir